# concatenation vs multiple rounds of HMAC

Tags: hmac, aws

I was studying the AWS request signature process and found that they derive the signing key from multiple sources ([one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/77372/unusual-design-aspects-of-aws-hmac-based-authentication-v4) and [two](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102594/how-the-aws-signature-works-in-depth) related questions).

Specifically this:

```
kSecret = Your AWS Secret Access Key
kDate = HMAC("AWS4" + kSecret, Date)
kRegion = HMAC(kDate, Region)
kService = HMAC(kRegion, Service)
kSigning = HMAC(kService, "aws4_request")
```

I do understand why the use of the various fields.

But why not simply concatenating all fields and hashing once? Like `HMAC(kSecret, date + region + etc.)`

I feel that I'm missing some basic theory but I can't express what it is.

Thanks!

Comment: If you concatenate variable length fields you need some means of distinguishing ("abc", "d") from ("ab", "cd"). Taking a blind guess, *maybe* they did it this way to make key derivation easier for programmers. Particularly PHP programmers, since dealing with binary strings, type conversion, string escaping, and encoding is all a little awkward.